# Can't read a csv file into pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

Hi I have a csv file that looks like this

[image]

I'm reading this into pandas with this

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(project+dataitem1+'.csv', header=0, delimiter=',',names=['Name', 'companyId', 'Industry', 'Filing Date', 'Instance Type', 'Fiscal End Date', 'Fiscal Year', 'Fiscal Quarter', 'Security'])
```

And I can't read it properly!  I've tried using sep = ','.  I've tried it where I put a header in and throw in a header=0.

when I go into my python interpreter and type

data1['Name']

I get

```
Norman Hay plc                                         875412
HDFC Bank Limited                                      101677
Indigo Properties Australia Limited                  11368636
```

When I expected:

```
Norman Hay plc                                         
HDFC Bank Limited                                      
Indigo Properties Australia Limited
```

When I open the file in notepad this is what I get:

> ﻿Norman Hay plc,875412,Chemicals,2008-09-19 00:00:00.000,Original
> Instance,2008-03-31 00:00:00.000,2008,1,LTM,Ordinary Shares

So there is a comma, but it doesn't seem to read the first comma.  why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The header count is less then the data column count. Also use None for the header parameter.

Try this code:

```
ss = '''
Norman Hay plc,875412,Chemicals,2008-09-19 00:00:00.000,Original Instance,2008-03-31 00:00:00.000,2008,1,LTM,Ordinary Shares
'''.strip()

with open ('data.csv','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write test file

###################################

import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, sep=',',names=['Name', 'companyId', 'Industry', 'Filing Date', 'Instance Type', 'Fiscal End Date', 'Fiscal Year', 'Fiscal Quarter', 'Security','Share Type'])

print(data1.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
           Name  companyId   Industry              Filing Date      Instance Type          Fiscal End Date  Fiscal Year  Fiscal Quarter Security       Share Type
 Norman Hay plc     875412  Chemicals  2008-09-19 00:00:00.000  Original Instance  2008-03-31 00:00:00.000         2008               1      LTM  Ordinary Shares
```